# Why does locals() return a strange self referential list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.6, python-internals, locals

So I'm using locals() to grab some arguments in the function. Works nicely:

```
def my_function(a, b):
    print locals().values()

>>> my_function(1,2)
[1, 2]
```

Standard stuff. But now let's introduce a list comprehension:

```
def my_function(a, b):
    print [x for x in locals().values()]

>>> my_function(1,2)
[[...], 1, 2]
```

Ehh? Why has it inserted a self-reference?

Comment: Not in Python 2.7 it doesn't. Python 2.6, yes.

Comment: why do you only print the value? why don't you print the key as weel, to see what refers to what?

Comment: @MartijnPieters was it a bug in 2.6? It disappears in 2.7 yes but unfortunately I don't have the luxury of a 2.7 installation.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: most likely a change in the namespace handling of list comprehensions; the list comp output appears to be stored in the locals namespace. I see it in Python 2.5 as well.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: If you need to filter this out in a list comprehension use `[v for k, v in locals().iteritems() if not k.startswith('_[')]`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python versions before 2.7 and 3.1 used suboptimal bytecode to produce a list comprehension. In those Python versions, the list comprehension was stored in a local variable (or even a global, if at module scope):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     return [x for x in y]
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 DUP_TOP             
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (_[1])
              7 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (y)
             10 GET_ITER            
        >>   11 FOR_ITER                13 (to 27)
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
             17 LOAD_FAST                0 (_[1])
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             23 LIST_APPEND         
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           11
        >>   27 DELETE_FAST              0 (_[1])
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `_[1]` local variable is the list-in-progress. When nesting list comprehensions it would use increasing integers to refer to the result:

```
>>> def bar():
...     return [[x for x in y] for z in spam]
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 DUP_TOP             
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (_[1])
              7 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (spam)
             10 GET_ITER            
        >>   11 FOR_ITER                40 (to 54)
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (z)
             17 LOAD_FAST                0 (_[1])
             20 BUILD_LIST               0
             23 DUP_TOP             
             24 STORE_FAST               2 (_[2])
             27 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (y)
             30 GET_ITER            
        >>   31 FOR_ITER                13 (to 47)
             34 STORE_FAST               3 (x)
             37 LOAD_FAST                2 (_[2])
             40 LOAD_FAST                3 (x)
             43 LIST_APPEND         
             44 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           31
        >>   47 DELETE_FAST              2 (_[2])
             50 LIST_APPEND         
             51 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           11
        >>   54 DELETE_FAST              0 (_[1])
             57 RETURN_VALUE
```

By looping over `locals().values()` you included a reference to the list-in-progress in the return value. Note that the bytecode uses a `DELETE_FAST` to clean up the local name to try and avoid the namespace pollution.

This was optimized for Python 3.1 and 2.7, see [issue 2183](http://bugs.python.org/issue2183). The list result under construction was moved to the stack instead. The optimization changed the `LIST_APPEND` bytecode to reference what list on the stack to append to, removing the need to use `DUP_TOP` -> `STORE_FAST` at the start, `LOAD_FAST` each iteration and `DELETE_FAST` after the list comprehension.